# Game theory : winning positions ?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Can we apply the Sprague-Grundy theorem/algorithm if the final position is a winning position ?

If we have a finite two-person impartial game where the final position is a loosing position, we can apply the Sprague-Grundy method to find which player has a winning strategy by assigning each position a nonnegative integer, called the nimber :

- The nimber of the final position is $0$
- The nimber of a position is the mex (minimal excluded number) of all the nimbers of all the next possible positions

We have the very useful property :

- The nimber of the sum of two games is the XOR of the numbers of the two games

Now, from a position with non-zero nimber, the winning-strategy is to go to a position with zero nimber (it is proven to be always possible). The (nimber=0)- positions correspond to the loosing positions.

How to do the same if the final position is winning ?

Comment: Is "nimber" a nickname for "number" or is it a distinct notion?

Comment: It is a nonnegative number associated with a position in a (generalised) game of Nim. This is all linked with the Sprague-Grundy theorem :)

Comment: Nim games where the last person to move loses are called misère games.  See this previous math exchange question["Nimbers for misère games"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375114/nimbers-for-mis%C3%A8re-games) and the website [miseregames.org](http://www.miseregames.org/) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jaap Scherphuis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/362967/jaap-scherphuis) [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404499/game-theory-winning-positions#comment4964693_2404499), if you change "terminal positions are losing positions" to "terminal positions are winning positions", then you are considering a game under the "[misère play convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mis%C3%A8re#Mis.C3.A8re_game)" (as opposed to the "[normal play convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_play_convention)").

Now, if you have an [impartial game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game) (the sort of game you would apply Sprague-Grundy to) under misère play, and just want to see who has a winning strategy, then the difficulty of that depends a lot on the game you're considering.

If your question is just something like "can a tiny modification to the method of the Sprague-Grundy theorem handle all impartial games under misère play?", then the answer is "no", as in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/377633/26369) to [Nimbers for misère games](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/375114/26369).

More broadly, many papers have been written on handling [sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sum) of games that are coming from a single ruleset (e.g. [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), or [Kayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayles)), both general theory and papers on specific games. Sometimes that's a straightforward analysis, and sometimes it's not. You can see a lot of these papers at [miseregames.org](http://www.miseregames.org/).

---

The Sprague Grundy Theorem also tells you a lot more than just how to play a sum of Nim games and Kayles, it says that the nimber tells you enough information to determine who wins a sum of that game in combination with *any* other impartial games in normal play. However, there cannot be a similarly tidy result for misère games.

There *is* theory (see, for instance, section V.3 of Aaron N. Siegel's [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082185190X)) that lets you discard some of the information of an impartial game when  misère-played in a sum of arbitrary impartial games. However, I do not believe this simplifies things significantly in any known nontrivial ruleset. For example, in my paper [Equality Classes of Nim Positions under Misère Play](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol16.html), it is shown that: In the case of Nim, the only simplification this buys you is basically the ability to subtract 1 from any pair of odd-sized heaps (or add 1 to any pair of even-sized heaps).